# How to get Active/Inactive Topics in JSON format within a configurable timeline

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Can somebody explain or provide some useful link to get active/inactive topics in **Kafka** using **Java**?

Comment: Hi Christo, what do you mean by inactive? do you mean deleted?

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, you are looking for `AdminClient` provided by Apache Kafka. Here is a [Link](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html) of its official documentation. This API provides various methods - displaying a list of topics, create/delete topics and other features like delete consumer groups, create partitions, etc.

I am writing a sample code that I have used in my project for topic creation using the AdminClient API.

```
public static NewTopic createTopics(String topicName) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\kafka_2.12-2.3.0\\kafkaproperty\\kafka.properties")));
    AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties);
    NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(topicName, 1, (short) 1); //new NewTopic(topicName, numPartitions, replicationFactor)

    List<NewTopic> newTopics = new ArrayList<NewTopic>();
    newTopics.add(newTopic);
    adminClient.createTopics(newTopics); // Creation of new topic
    adminClient.listTopics(); // List of topics which you can convert into JSON

    adminClient.close();
    return newTopic;
}
```

I hope you find this helpful. If you have any questions please feel free to ask.